# Mariadb performance issues between 10.0 and 10.4

Tags: performance, mariadb, upgrade

We're currently running MariaDB 10.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 and are looking to upgrade to MariaDB 10.4 on 18.04 but we've run into a strange issue. When testing vanilla installs of 10.0 against 10.4 the performance of the 10.4 install is about 50% slower on the same hardware. We're running these on GCP 2 core 7GB VMs.

I've setup a test table on both instances that looks like this:

```
create table if not exists testinsert_aria
(
        id int primary key,
        description varchar(255),
        colorder int
) engine=aria;
```

and setup a test script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
START_DATE=`date`
END_DATE=`date`
START_ID=0
IDX=0

while [ $START_ID -lt 10001 ]
do
        START_ID=$[$START_ID+1]
        SQL_CMD="echo \"insert into testinsert_aria values($START_ID,'this is a test',1)\" | mysql -uroot testdb"
        eval $SQL_CMD
done
END_DATE=`date`
echo "$(($(date -d "$END_DATE" '+%s') - $(date -d "$START_DATE" '+%s')))"
```

On the 10.0 instance this runs in about 48 seconds, but on the 10.4 instance it takes about 70 seconds. I'm using htop, iostat, and ioping to monitor the system and I'm not seeing any stress on the CPU or the disk. Occasionally one core will go to 100% but for the most part the cores stay at about 45%.

I'm much more familiar with SQL Server than I am with Mariadb, but there doesn't seem to be many tuning options available for the aria engine. I see the same issues with the innodb engine. I've also tested it with Mariadb 10.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 and seen the same results so it doesn't seem to be OS related. I'm running with a separate data SSD data disk that's setup with XFS (also tried EXT4 but no major differences). I've played with the IO scheduler and haven't seen any differences. I'm somewhat at a loss as to what's going on. I would imagine if there was this big of a performance difference between 10.0 and 10.4 that there'd be bunch of threads about it but I can't find anything. I've also expressed the test in a stored proc to remove the client and it's still the same results. The average query time on the 10.4 instance is about 3x longer when viewing it through the slow_log and the query_response_time shows the same.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Additional information request data from 10.0.nn and 10.4.nn 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible benchmark.  Unless you really run mysql from shell scripts.  It is not distinguishing among

- OS changes
- Shell changes
- Launching `mysql`
- Granting access in mysql
- Doing a trivial one-line `INSERT`

By connecting *once* you will gain a significant speedup.
By batching the rows that you insert, you will gain *another* significant speedup.  (In another context, I have seen 10x.)

I don't know if the Engine=Aria is any worse than the standard InnoDB, but that could be another thing.

Comment: I've tested the same insert with a store procedure as well to try to reduce the client and compared the execution times using the slow log and I get the same results. I also ran it with Ubuntu 16.04 with Mariadb 10.4 and saw the same results so that should eliminate most of those variables. Also the app that is using this is doing a large number of single line inserts so single insert performance is important. Aria is a crash safe MyISAM storage so it should be faster than InnoDB, but it's also slower when using InnoDB.

Comment: Does your app create a new connection for each INSERT like the benchmark?

Comment: No, but as mentioned I've run the same process via a stored proc which will not create a new connection per insert and that's given me the same results.